# Formula based on a specific part of data date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking to have a countifs formula count based on the time provided as part of a date. I do not want to manipulate the raw data i just want to ignore the whole number of a date, I need the decimal place to determine if it is greater or less that .6667.

```
=COUNTIFS(DATA!$C:$C,">="&$A$1,DATA!$C:$C,"<="&$L$1,DATA!$V:$V,"<.6667",DATA!$E:$E,5)
```

DATA SOURCE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uGexXFJ-vIngyzjNXJOVhsO_iFfn3E21XojCjwrhH2g/edit?usp=sharing

Desired result will return a the count if UTC time is greater than or less than .6667 (4:00:00 pm(local)).  This will allow me to determine if the reviews are atributed to the Lunch or Dinner shift.

Comment: Can you share sample of your data and your expected result? Can you also clarify why your formula you shared isn't working?

Comment: I have edited the original prompt with a google sheet for data, and a expected result.

I hope this will help you, help me.

Answer (score 1):

To to determine if the reviews are attributed to the Lunch or Dinner shift, your interest should be in time only. So you may safely ignore the date part and thus the `DATA!$C:$C,">="&$A$1,DATA!$C:$C,"<="&$L$1` part in your formula.

Basically what is left with are just 2 criteria:

1. `Overall Rating = 5`
2. `Submission Time < 0.6667`.

That being said, let's try to get the desired solution step-by-step (you may find it extra descriptive, it's just to make sure we are on the same page):

1. Change column C (Submission Date Time (UTC)) from `Text` to `Date & time` format. This can easily be done by omitting "- ". Select the whole column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. In the *"Find what"* field, type "`-`", leave the *"Replace with"* field `blank`, and click *"Replace all"* button.
2. Since you are using column V for the `<.6667` criteria, put the formula `=C2-INT(C2)` in row 2 of that column, then copy and populate rest of the rows. This'll get us the time only - that's what we are looking for.
3. Finally, get the desired result by using the formula:

   `=COUNTIFS(data!$V:$V,"<.6667",data!$E:$E,5)`